# Monitor delete statements on a specific table on DB2 LUW

Tags: db2, db2-luw

**Background**

User is claiming that records are deleted from a specific table, but nobody knows why. They are not sure if it's an application error or done by a user.

**Question**

Is it possible to monitor / catch / trace delete statements executed against a specific table?

My first idea was to create an event monitor, but I can't limit it to a specific table or a specific kind of statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [AUDIT TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050609.html) statement on this table using an [AUDIT POLICY](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050607.html) with the `EXECUTE` category.
Or create an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger.

Comment: This is a good idea, but it as far as I see it's also not possible to limit the monitoring to delete statements only.  Or do I miss something?

Comment: If you mean auditing delete statements only, then yes, it's not possible.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I'm pretty sure I can use it sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Try a [USAGE LIST](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0058647.html)

> A usage list is a database object that records each DML statement section that references a particular table or index.

Comment: The [MON_GET_TABLE_USAGE_LIST](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0059274.html) function doesn't have an information about the user or application issued the statement. There is no even a statement text there. Only executable_id which can be used to find the statement text, if it's still in the package cache or in an event monitor for package cache, if the latter has been created and is active.

Comment: Yes. As Mark points out, you would need to take the executable_id and get the statement text from e.g. `MON_GET_PKG_CACHE_STMT` or elsewhere